# R won't update the data.table package for me

Tags: r, data.table

I'm on OSX Mavericks 10.9.5

When I run `install.packages("data.table")` I keep getting

```
There is a binary version available (and will be installed) but the source version is later:
           binary source
data.table  1.9.2  1.9.4

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/3.0/data.table_1.9.2.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1270580 bytes (1.2 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 1.2 Mb


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/nz/5zx8zy7d1yg4fxhtttcl7s_c0000gn/T//Rtmp1aKmAP/downloaded_packages
```

and my version of data.table won't update to 1.9.4

Here's my `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.3
```

Why am I getting this and how do I update to version 1.9.4?

Comment: Maybe `install.packages("data.table", type="source")`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg that worked.  Can't thank you enough.